# Its possible create a dropdown menu using ghost?

Tags: node.js, ghost

I'm new using ghost, it's possible create this using ghost?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if there is an easy way to create a dropdown menu from the ghost backend i am afraid there is none.

You can find a navigation.hbs in the standard theme (Casper) partials folder that you could style as you wish.

Or you can search for a theme that has dropdowns implemented.